# Summation equation in Java?

Tags: java, math, calculus

[image: Summation Equation]

I would like to know how I would go about writing this summation equation in java. But, the trick is, I need the summation to be equal to an amount.

```
x= Total Loss Streak amount
sb= Starting Bet
m= multiplier
```

The whole equation will equal to the current amount of currency in one's account. The amount of times the summation can complete itself while adding up needs to be less than or equal to the amount of currency in ones account.

Fyi, this is for a dicebot that work's on peerbet.org and I want to be able to show the user how many times he can loose in a row without wasting all his money.

If this question is bad, please do not answer it and let me delete it. Also, it thought the middle part was code, so I had to put it as such or it wouldn't let me post.

Comment: To be clear, which variable are you solving for?

Comment: Solving for x... While the whole thing is lessthan or equal to y

Comment: This isn't a Java question, this is a math question. Suggest migrating to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renaming sb to just b. This is just a sum of a geometric progression

[image: sum = b * (m<sup>2</sup> - m<sup>x + 1</sup>) / (1 - m)]

In Java, you can write:

```java
return b * (m * m - Math.pow(m, x + 1)) / (1 - m);
```

This will be considerably faster than using a loop, although you must check that `m` is not 1.

If you want to *solve* for `x` given a sum `S` then a rearrangement of the formula gives the following Java code:

```java
double x = Math.log(m * m - S * (1 - m) / b) / log(m) - 1;
```

and truncate this result to get the integral value of `x` where the next integer bankrupts the player.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to sum up 1 + 2 + ... + x so that it equals sb * m^i -- where sb is an amount of money, i is an interest rate and m is the number of months.

Comment: I think re-answering is worth a punt. I'm starting to think that I've solved the wrong problem here.

Comment: @michaeladair In that case, make sure you understand Bathsheba's answer correctly. If what you want is to find an `x` so that `2 + 3 + ... + x` equals (the constant value) `sb * m^i` then this answer is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: apparently we are solving for x. still easily doable with a loop.

```
int sum = 0;
int x =2;
while(sum<=amount){
   sum+=sb*(Math.pow(m,x));
}    
return x;
```

---

---

A summation is really just an adding for loop right?

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=2; i<x; i++){
    sum+=sb*(Math.pow(m,i));
}

return sum;
```

Comment: That is my understanding. All those equations with "E" in them got a lot less scary when I realized it was a mere for loop. 
Source: Cryptography class

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear I'm reading your formula correctly: are you summing up integers from 2 to x on the left-hand side of the *equals* sign, and you want that sum to be equal to the term on the right-hand side?

In that case, we could do the following transformation:

[image]

(Note that the first step might not be what you had in mind.)

We can now easily solve this using the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to get:

[image]

Assuming that we're calculating in the reals, note that the root is only defined for non-negative arguments. The result of taking that root yields a non-negative number and substracting that non-negative number from `-1` would give something `<= -1`, i.e., a negative number. Dividing it by `2` won't make it positive, either, but we've assumed from the get-go that our x must be `>= 2`, or else the very first sum wouldn't make any sense.

Therefore we can disregard the `-` case of the `+/-` in the formula altogether. Hence:

[image]

This should be straight-forward to translate into Java code, but note that the result is likely not to be an integer, so you will have to round if you're looking for an upper bound.

Comment: @Bathsheba Kudo, good call! I've included an argument why we can drop one of the two cases.